# Selenium: Determine status of WebElement by CssSelector

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, css-selectors

I am identifying a clickable `WebElement` by `CssSelector`. An example code I am using is:

```
String selectorString = "a.some-text.item";

WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selectorString));
we.click();
```

The problem is, that after the item has been clicked its `CssSelector` changes to `a.some-text.item.clicked`. I can still securely identify it by using above `selectorString` variable. However, I only want to click it if it has not been clicked before.

How can I determine the items status, i.e. whether its `cssSelector` name is `a.some-text.item` or `a.some-text.item.clicked`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only want to click it if it has not been clicked before.

Try using [`:not(selector)`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) function of `cssSelector` to determine only unclicked element :-

```
String selectorString = "a.some-text.item:not(.clicked)";

WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selectorString));
we.click();
```

**Edited** :- If you want to just determine whether element has contains `clicked` class or not after clicking then try as below :-

```
String selectorString = "a.some-text.item";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selectorString)).click();

//Now verify element clicked or not 
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selectorString));
String msg =  (we.getAttribute("class").contains("clicked")) ? "element clicked" : "element not clicked";
System.out.println(msg);
```

Comment: This just gives me a timeout. I can find the element with `a.some-text.item` even after it has been changed to `a.some-text.item.clicked` on the website. After the element has been matched I want to determine, if I matched it with the `.clicked` extension or without it. Ideally, without having to wait for a timeout.

Comment: @nautical actually I'm not sure how would you like to determine whether element clicked or not, but I'm just trying to understand and edited my answer with my understanding, try it if any confusion let me know for better solution. Thanks..:)

Comment: @nautical Or if want to get only unclicked element, to avoid timeout exception you can use `findElements` with previous answer cssSelector using `:not(selector)` function and check if list size greater that 0 means you have found unclicked element otherwise element has been clicked, let Me know if not clear..